# Running Python in CMD not working

Tags: python, windows-8, cmd, environment-variables

I am a Python beginner and I am having trouble running Python from CMD. I have added the Python installation directory as a PATH variable (;C:\Python27). I am able to run the Python Interpreter from CMD, however when I issue a command like "python file.py command" from CMD, it returns "Error2, Python can't open, no such file/directory".

So what I do is go to "cd C:\Folder\Folder2\My_Python_Files", then type the "file.py command" each and every time. Is there faster or more efficient way of doing this? I am currently running Python2.7 on Windows 8.

Comment: Add the folder containing your `file.py` to `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

Comment: Where is `file.py` and what is the current directory when you type `python file.py`?  Adding the Python directory to the path just makes Python itself globally accessible; it doesn't make all programs written in Python automatically accessible.  You still have to be in the same directory as a particular Python file to run it (unless you do even more path manipulations).

Comment: how would windows command know where the file is without specifying the absolute path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run `python <script>`, it requires an actual path to the script being provided. You cannot specify "file.py" alone, unless it is right there in your current directory.

In windows, here are two steps you can take:

1. Associate .py files with python. Then you can run them directly without the `python` command as: `/path/to/file.py`
   (right click a .py -> properties -> change to associate with python.exe)
2. Further step: Add a location to your `PATH` environment which will contain your python scripts. From there, you can just do `file.py` and it will be found in your search path.
   So you could add `C:\Folder\Folder2\My_Python_Files` to your `PATH` and that is where you can store your executable python scripts.

Also you can set the PATH variable temporarily during a shell session:

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\path\to\project
```

Comment: I followed step #2 and added C:\Folder\Folder2\My_Python_Files to my PATH variable, and it worked. So it requires setting the path to every script you want to access using CMD? Thanks, you've been helpful :)

Comment: Generally when you want to make a command-line script available to the entire system, you place it in a system PATH location. It is the same with `POSIX`. But in `POSIX` we have symlinks which means you can simply link it into a system path location. Best bet for you here is to just copy it to your system path when it is ready, and during dev you should just work on it with direct paths. Or, like you said...add them to your path. You can actually set the PATH temporarily with `SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\path\to\project`

Answer (score 2):

Just like `PATH` environment variable lists several directories for the system to search for executables, the `PYTHONPATH` do the same for Python to search for `.py` files. If you want scripts in a folder to be globally accessible (i.e. you can reference them by name just like you want, or you can import them from other scripts), add that folder to `PYTHONPATH` (create it if it doesn't exist).

Note that the command to invoke a script that is in your `PYTHONPATH` is:

```
python -m file [<script arguments>]
```

(i.e. use the `-m` option to treat it as a [module](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html), and don't use the extension `.py`)

Here's [an article](http://www.stereoplex.com/blog/understanding-imports-and-pythonpath) explaining in more detail how Python finds its source files (both in the command line and through `import`).

Note that you can also refer to the script by using its full path:

```
python C:\Folder\Folder2\My_Python_Files\file.py command
```

But by doing this, other files in the same folder that this script might reference through `import` might not work (since Python doesn't know where to search for them).

Comment: This is good info, but it is actually not related to the PYTHONPATH. That is meant for imports. The OP is trying to run them as the entry point, which means it has to do with `PATH`.

Comment: You're right, I haven't noticed that! But I believe you can access it using `python -m file` (without `.py`) if `file.py`is in PYTHONPATH, is that correct? I'll check, and update the answer.

Comment: I've created the PYTHONPATH variable and put in the directory where my "file.py" is located. It still returns the same error on CMD when I try to access it, "no such file exists"

Comment: @MikhailOnate I just updated my answer, thanks to the comment from @jdi. You need to call your file in a different way: `python -m file command`

Comment: I was able to run it by adding the script directory to the PATH variable. Thanks for all the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the project's folder is in the PATH, you cannot call the file unless you are inside the project's folder. Don't create PATHs for projects, unless they are needed; it's unnecessary.  
 
    Just transverse to the file's directory and run the command inside the directory. That will work. 
 
    If the project will be used by other projects/files, you can use PYTHONPATH to set the directory, so the other projects can successfully access it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I was able to run it by adding it to the PATH.

Comment: If all the answers helped, upvote them all, and select one of them as the accepted answer; that helps both you, and others who might have similar problems later.

Comment: I'm still unable to vote up answers due to the newness of my account. Will do so soon. Thanks!